# In Hammerfight, how do you catch a weapon?

Tags: hammerfight

I am currently stuck in the flail throwing part and I can only catch it randomly. Do I have to hold the left mouse and catch it? or do i have to click at the right moment or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to hold the left button and let the solid part of the weapon touch you, not just the chain. You'll then catch and equip the weapon.

More generally, if you have a weapon selected, and hold your left click, you can catch items that touch you or your weapon. You can do this with weapon that you dropped, that enemy dropped, armor and throwing blades.

Comment: so in that stage, i just throw my flail, then start holding the left button and keep going at the flail until it "reconnects" automatically?

Comment: Yes, you just have to leave it fall back on you, it'll reconnect. You can see you are in "grabbing mode" when you have some kinds of arms extending from your machine.

Comment: You need to make sure you have a standard weapon in the open hold slot, because left clicking with anything else will perform a variety of actions but *not* the collection one.

Comment: Note: Don't try and catch the part where it connects to your ship-thing, catch the damaging part of the weapon. i.e. the 'ball' of the flail.